# After form submit how can i check submitted value integer or not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have text field with add button. When I click add button, I need to check entered text box value is "NUMBER" or not. If it's not an integer and decimals we need to show alert. How can I do this. If it's an integer and decimals then it is okay.

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">


    <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="todoText" placeholder="add new todo here">
      <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {


  $scope.addTodo = function() {
  console.log($scope.todoText);
  var filter = /^[a-zA-Z!”$%&’()*\+,\/;\[\\\]\^_`{|}~]+$/;
            var test_bool = filter.test($scope.todoText);
            if (test_bool == true)
            {
                alert('Please enter valid number');

                return false;
            }
  };



}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/37117/)

Comment: All you wish is to check that a number has been entered or not, how come your regex is so complelx ? How about a simple `/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]*$/` ? Or use the `isNan` function !

Comment: want to check number and decimal using regex@Exception_al

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if the value is number or not.

```
if (isNaN(test_bool))
{
    alert('Please enter valid number');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @itsme `22.s` is not a number!

Comment: want to check number and decimal using regex. can you help me on this

Comment: This will work with number and decimals, you want to check with that `.s`,which is not a number. So what exactly do you want to check?

Comment: instaed of using isNaN i want to use regex pattern to check this number and decimal

Comment: I got that. But 2.s is not a number!

Comment: yeah ok can you please help me on that regex

Comment: @itsme is 2.s only valid input or there could be some others?

Comment: @itsme okay it is getting confusing here. Tell me what all possible values you want to validate.

Comment: after submit we need check numbers and decimal number ..if we enter character we need to show alert

Answer (score 1):

try this:->

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {


 $scope.addTodo = function() {
 console.log($scope.todoText);

        if (isNaN(Number($scope.todoText)))
        {
            alert('Please enter valid number');

            return false;
        }
  };
}
```

Comment: want to check number and decimal using regex

Answer (score 0):

you can test whether number or not with `isNumber()`

```
        if (!angular.isNumber($scope.todoText))
        {
            alert('Please enter valid number');

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: want to check number and decimal using regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use to check isNumeric function as below.

```
$.isNumeric( variable )
```